# How to validate two select inputs for equality

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have two select inputs with values, and I am trying to make a validation.

If the second select has value that equals to the first one, it should pop up a message to change the value.

I tried with `$.validator` but I still can't make it work.

```
$('#SubstituteUserGid').change(function () {
    $('#mainForm').validate({
        rules: {
            SubstituteUserGid: { notEqual: userName }
        }
    });
}); 
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value != param;
}, "Please specify a different (non-default) value");
```

And this is the HTML

```
<select asp-for="UserGid" data-val-required="Моля изберете служител"
        placeholder="Моля изберете служител" class="form-control" data-val="true">
    @foreach (var user in Model.AllActiveUsers)
    {
    <option value="@user.Gid" data-balance="@user.Balance">@user.Name</option>
    }
</select>


<select asp-for="SubstituteUserGid" class="form-control" data-val="true">
    <option value="">-- Без заместващ --</option>
    @foreach (var user in Model.AllActiveUsers)
    {
    <option value="@user.Gid">@user.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use `Remote` attribute which will serve your purpose greatly.

Say your model class as follows:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string UserGid {get; set;}

    [Remote(action: "IsUserGuidEquals", controller: "Validation",AdditionalFields = "UserGid", ErrorMessage = "UserId are equals! Please select different one!")]
    public string SubstituteUserGid {get; set;}
}
```

Then in `IsUserGuidEquals` method in your controller as follows:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult IsUserGuidEquals(string substituteUserGid, string userGid)
    {
        return Json(substituteUserGid != userGid,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, add same class like  activeuser and try it again,

```
<select asp-for="UserGid" data-val-required="Моля изберете служител"
        placeholder="Моля изберете служител" class="form-control activeuser" data-val="true">
    @foreach (var user in Model.AllActiveUsers)
    {
    <option value="@user.Gid" data-balance="@user.Balance">@user.Name</option>
    }
</select>


<select asp-for="SubstituteUserGid" class="form-control activeuser" data-val="true">
    <option value="">-- Без заместващ --</option>
    @foreach (var user in Model.AllActiveUsers)
    {
    <option value="@user.Gid">@user.Name</option>
    }
</select>


$('#SubstituteUserGid').change(function () {
    $('.activeuser').validate({
        rules: {
            SubstituteUserGid: { notEqual: userName }
        }
    });
}); 
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value != param;
}, "Please specify a different (non-default) value");
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I found a solution here https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/